# bash command output as parameters

Tags: bash, parameters

Assume that the command `alpha` produces this output:

```
a b c
d
```

If I run the command

```
beta $(alpha)
```

then `beta` will be executed with four parameters, `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"` and `"d"`.

But if I run the command

```
beta "$(alpha)"
```

then `beta` will be executed with one parameter, `"a b c d"`.

What should I write in order to execute `beta` with two parameters, `"a b c"` and `"d"`. That is, how do I force `$(alpha)` to return one parameter per output line from `alpha`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to anubhava's answer, if you are using `bash` 4 or later.

```
readarray -t args < <(alpha)
beta "${args[@]}"
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
$ alpha | xargs -d "\n" beta
```

Answer (score 2):

Do that in 2 steps in `bash`:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' a b < <(alpha)

beta "$a" "$b"
```

**Example:**

```
# set IFS to \n with -d'' to read 2 values in a and b
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' a b < <(echo $'a b c\nd')

# check a and b
declare -p a b
declare -- a="a b c"
declare -- b="d"
```

Answer (score -1):

Script beta.sh should fix your issue:

```
$ cat alpha.sh
#! /bin/sh
echo -e "a b c\nd"

$ cat beta.sh
#! /bin/sh
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(./alpha.sh); do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: This also subjects the output of `./alpha.sh` to pathname generation, which may not be desirable.

Comment: @chepner. Minus one, why? It's a simple example to show how to fix the issue, and it works. Obviously alpha.sh can be on the PATH directories and then you could avoid "./", but I wanted to focus the attention on fixing the issue and not on secondary issues...

Comment: It *doesn't* work, if `alpha` can output a line like `a * c`. This is not a secondary issue.

Comment: Please, can you provide an example string with echo that fails? I prefer to test it

Comment: I just did. Read [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for more detail.

Comment: This link uses IFS as suggested in my solution

Comment: It uses `IFS`, but not at all the way you do. Also read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor, a link to which is the *very first thing* on the page.

Comment: Very useful your link, I like it. Thanks for sharing! :)